# Active directory and IIS from internet

Tags: asp.net, iis

I would like to know if is possible access from SmartPhones to webserver IIS that belong to Active Directory "Windows Server 2008" all this from Internet

I have take a look to some importants question like this

[IIS and Active Directory Permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23372475/iis-and-active-directory-permissions)

[Controlling access to a website with IIS/Active Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918004/controlling-access-to-a-website-with-iis-active-directory)

[How do I access a Active directory enabled website from the internet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377864/how-do-i-access-a-active-directory-enabled-website-from-the-internet)

but still no sure if is possible

Thanks You

Comment: Yes. You configure your firewalls appropriately. But that's not really a question for Stack Overflow, you'd get better help on another Stack Exchange site.

Comment: Thank you very much. this is my firts time here, I don´t know how to move it. By the way, do you know where I can find some guide about this?